# setting environment variables from python code for spark

Tags: python, pyspark

I have set the environment variables in Mac os to run `pyspark`

```
export SPARK_HOME=/Users/devesh/Downloads/spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.6

export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/:$PYTHONPATH

export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip:$PYTHONPATH
```

The above lines does the work for me.

I am trying to replicate the above commands in python using the following lines of python code

```
os.environ['SPARK_HOME']="/Users/devesh/Downloads/spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.6"
spark_home=os.environ.get('SPARK_HOME',None)

sys.path.append("/Users/devesh/Downloads/spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/")

sys.path.insert(0,os.path.join(spark_home,'py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip'))
```

but it is not working. Please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last line of python code:

```
sys.path.insert(0,os.path.join(spark_home,'py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip'))
```

is inconsistent with your shell code. You may change it to:

```
sys.path.insert(0,os.path.join(spark_home,'python','lib','py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip'))
```