# Importing pyspark in a Jupyter Notebook launched from any directory

Tags: python, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

My OS is Ubuntu 16 and my goal is to `import pyspark` in a Jupyter Notebook without having to launch Jupyter Notebook (via the console) from within the directory where I installed Spark to. I tried it with `findspark` like so

```
import findspark
findspark.init("directory_where_I_installed_spark_to")
import pyspark
```

This works for one session, but when I shutdown the session and open the notebook again, `import pyspark` gets me `ImportError: No module 'pyspark'`. What am I missing?

Comment: You have to define environment variables , take look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35576621/setting-environment-variables-from-python-code-for-spark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reached my goal by editing the .bashrc file as outlined here https://medium.com/@GalarnykMichael/install-spark-on-ubuntu-pyspark-231c45677de0 (step number 7).

Answer (score 0):

if you add findspark.find()  after 2nd line of your code above 
what is the output you get both times ?

Comment: In both cases (launching Jupyter Notebook from my home directory and launching it from the Spark-directory) I get the same output, namely the directory where I installed Spark to.